# Redirecting after login to authorised user's relationship

Tags: php, laravel

After my users log in I want them to be redirected to a route which contains a slug of one of the models they are related to. I have edited the $redirectTo variable in the auth controller like this:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/auth()->user()->country->slug';
```

I have also tried

```
protected $redirectTo = '/{{auth()->user()->country->slug}}';
```

I am getting a property of non object error for both.

Any solution to this, so I can redirect my users to the route which contains the slug of their respective state?

Comment: How about double quotes?

Comment: @Chay22 I've tried it with single and double quotes, same 'property of non object' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to override `redirectPath` method in your `AuthController`

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    return auth()->user()->state->slug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well. Is there a similar function for redirecting after logout and registration?

Comment: checkout `getLogout` method in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait

Comment: @DanielPahor registration uses the same redirect path as login `redirectPath()` but for logout it uses `redirectAfterLogout` property you must override `logout()` method if you want to redirect user to their state's slug.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function to declare your class property, see http://php.net/language.oop5.properties

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

If you have property that must be use a function to define it use `__construct()` method like:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $myproperty;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myproperty = somefunction();
    }
}
```

But for this case you can't use that kind of way, since when class initiated no user authenticated yet. Instead you can use `authenticated()` method on your controller.

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function authenticated()
    {
        if($path = Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user()->state->slug){
            return redirect($path);
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```